# Scope of internal visibility modifier in Kotlin

Tags: visibility, kotlin

I have a problem understanding the internal access modifier. In my examples I could not produce any situation where it behaves different then public. Even if I create a jars I can access the internal functions in the jar from outside the jar (from a different package unrelated to the one used in the jar). In the documentation the term module is used but I could not find out what a module is exactly.

My questions thus are:

1. what is a module in kotlin?
2. how does the access modifier internal differs from the public modiefier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Kotlin compiler version M8 (0.8.11) ignores modules, more precisely, it works as if all your code were put into the same module, this is why you can't get a visibility error for `internal`.

Starting with the next milestone release, every IDE module you create has its own visibility scope, and when you try to access an `internal` declaration from one module in another, you get an error. Publics, on the other hand, are visible across the whole project.

**UPDATE**: This has not been turned on in M8, postponed for later

**UPDATE**: This has been turned on since [later Kotlin milestones and betas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611651/3679676)

Comment: What is the definition of "IDE module" you are referring to?

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA's terms: when you open a project in the IDE, it has may modules, each of which has a number of source roots and dependencies/classpath.

Comment: Now clear, for me it was a bit of confusion with Java's "package-private" concept.

Comment: Just FYI, can't find much use of `internal` visibility modifier. Typical project structure per "Clean Architecture" approach is highly modular which means, for example, domain entities and services are in standalone module, and their properties and functions (other than `private`) have to be declared `public` in order to cross module's boundaries. For me that's an invasion of `public` keywords in source code. Any advice how can I make it less verbose?

Comment: @AndreyBreslav are visibility scopes still disabled in M12?

Comment: Yes, we are planning to finally enable them in the next milestone

Comment: They are enabled, see notes on this topic in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34611651/3679676